# Get all children of a SilverStripe page except those of a certain page type

Tags: silverstripe

I am working on a SilverStripe page type that is meant to get all children of a parent nav item EXCEPT any children that may be of page type `PDFTemplate`. I'm used to getting all the child elements but when it comes to excluding a particular child based on the template type, I'm not sure how to proceed.

This is the function that is getting the children of the parent nav item:

```
<% if $Children %>
    <div class=“Centers-Links-Area”>
        <% loop $Children %>
            <div class="Centers-Ex-Block clearfix">
                <a href="$Link">
                    <% if $CentersSubpageImage %>
                        <img class="image" src="$CentersSubpageImage.URL" />
                    <% end_if %>
                    <p>$H1</p>
                </a>
            </div>
        <% end_loop%>
    </div>
<% end_if %>
```

What I want to do is, if any of the children is of page type `PDFTemplate`, I want to hide the "Centers-Links-Area" div completely. Where can I place an if-statement to do such a check based on page type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<% loop $Children %>
    <% if $ClassName != "PDFTemplate" %>
        (your link html goes here)
    <% end_if %>
<% end_loop %>
```

Answer (score 5):

While Jono's answer covers exact matches of class names (which sounds like it works for your exact scenario), it does not handle an inheritance case where another class extends `PDFTemplate` and you want to prevent *any version* of `PDFTemplate` from displaying (which may be a valid issue for some)

Below is a example of page templates extending various classes

```
- Page
  - HomePage
  - PDFTemplate
    - SpecialPDFTemplate
  - ContactPage
```

Jono's answer doesn't prevent `SpecialPDFTemplate` from being displayed as `$ClassName != 'PDFTemplate'` will pass.

To prevent this, we can utilise a function [`Object::is_a()`](http://api.silverstripe.org/master/class-Object.html#_is_a). This is an instance function on all classes that extend `Object` and can be used like `$is_a('PDFTemplate')` in the template.

Your snippet will end up looking like this:

```
<% if $Children %>
    <div class=“Centers-Links-Area”>
        <% loop $Children %>
            <% if not $is_a('PDFTemplate') %>
            <div class="Centers-Ex-Block clearfix">
                <a href="$Link">
                    <% if $CentersSubpageImage %>
                        <img class="image" src="$CentersSubpageImage.URL" />
                    <% end_if %>
                    <p>$H1</p>
                </a>
            </div>
            <% end_if %>
        <% end_loop%>
    </div>
<% end_if %>
```

Again, while Jono's answer isn't wrong, this is a use case they may affect some people.

Comment: Great tip, this may be better depending on your setup. Will add that to my tool kit.

Comment: Good point! Luckily, I don't believe there will any classes that extend PDFTemplate, since it's rarely going to be used. However, this is good to note for anything in the future that may be more complex.